# Changing registration form in shopware 6 - initialCountryId / disable names for companies

Tags: registration, shopware6

I want to change the registration form a little bit. For example I want "Germany" to be preselected in the form. I took a look at the code and there is a field for it

```
{% block component_address_form_country_select %}
    {% set initialCountryId = 'c73fb8a7edd34096af700f45bb4872a3' %}
    {{parent()}}
{% endblock %}
```

I manually set the initalCountryId to Germany but this also should be possible from the admin backend or is this really the way to go? I also want to disable the fields name and surname for company registration, is this possible from the admin backend or do we need to change a twig file here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your default country on sales-channel level. It is then also preselected in the checkout and registration form. So I don't think your change is necessary.

Regarding the surname and lastname, it's not possible to deactivate it by default, you need to provide them during registration. So there are two possibilities I guess:

- Hiding it in the template and provide dummy data via the form(because they are a required fields)
- Changing the registration validation via plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I defined the default country on sales channel level still there is no country preselected. I changed to the default theme and deactivated all plugins and there is still no preselection. 

Is this the right place to define the country? Maybe it's a bug on my shopware version 6.4.4.1.

I managed to hide the fields now I only need to provide the dummy data. Thanks again!

Comment: I think this was added in a later version - can you check the current version of shopware?

Comment: I tested in the latest version the default country is set to germany but there is still nothing preselected for a registration so maybe it's a bug or I am looking at the wrong place.

I went in the admin backend to Storefront --> General --> General Settings --> Default country and set it to Germany